# Expected Value using Moment Generating Function

Tags: expected-value, moments, moment-generating-function

Let $M_Xt$ be the MGF of the random variable $X$. Define $S_X(t)=log_{10}M_xt$. 
I am trying to show that $\frac{d}{dt}S_X(t)|_{t=0}=E[X]$

Here's what I did:
$$E[X]=\frac{d}{dt}M_X(t)|_{t=0}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}S_X(t)|_{t=0}=(\frac{1}{M_xt})(\frac{d}{dt}M_X(t))|_{t=0}$$
then I'm stuck.
How do I show that $\frac{1}{M_xt}=1$?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that $S_X(t)$ is defined using the base 10 logarithm instead of the natural logarithm? Anyway, in the last line you need to evaluate $M_X(t)^{-1}$ for $t=0$. Since the MGF is $M_X(t) = \mathbb E[e^{tX}]$, we have $M_X(0) =\mathbb E[1] = 1$ and thus $M_X(0)^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.